# mvc3 best way to convert anonymous type to an ienumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable, anonymous-types

I have a model that uses an IEnumerable to return multiple rows using a foreach statement in the view. The issue is that I am using a Join because I need data from 2 different tables which turns the ienumerable into an anonymous type and is causing errors; whats the best way I can fix this?

```
 var Ieposts = (from t in db.Threadposts join p in db.profiles on t.profileID equals p.profileID  where t.threadID == id  select new
                    {
                       firstname = p.firstname,
                        lastname = p.lastname,
                        articles = p.articlecount,
                       city = p.city,
                       state = p.state,
                       post = t.post
                    }).ToList();
```

I am only getting out the fields that I need because that increases database performance. Any suggestions would be great

Comment: It's not the join that is creating the anonymous type.  It's the "select new" part.

Answer (score 1):

I think you really need to learn a bit more about Entity Framework and Linq in general.

Joins do not create anonymous types, nor is there any problem with getting an enumerable from an anonymous type.  Just call .AsEnumerable() from the query.

However, I suspect this is not what you're trying to do.  What you actually want is a concrete return type.  In That case, you probably want to create a type for this:

```
public class IEPost {
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public int Articles {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;} 
    public string State {get;set:}
    public Post Post {get;set;}
}
```

Then you create your query like so (note the "new IEPost" part):

```
var Ieposts = (from t in db.Threadposts 
               join p in db.profiles on t.profileID equals p.profileID
               where t.threadID == id  select new IEPost
               {
                   FirstName = p.firstname,
                   LastName = p.lastname,
                   Articles = p.articlecount,
                   City = p.city,
                   State = p.state,
                   Post = t.post
                }).ToList();
```